# How can I send push notification from PHP website to iOS and Android?

Tags: php, android, ios, push

How I can send push notification from PHP website to iOS devices and Android devices?

Is there any tutorial for that?

Comment: You can use firebase and it's web api to sending notification from website.

Answer (score 2):

You can use several premade services for push notifications like Firebase Messaging, One Signal, etc. For Firebase cloud Messaging Integration with PHP, please visit [this Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client). After setting up, Just Send this POST request with the user token

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...PbJ_uNasm

{
  "message": {
    "token" : <token of destination app>,
    "notification": {
      "title": "FCM Message",
      "body": "This is a message from FCM"
    },
    "webpush": {
      "headers": {
        "Urgency": "high"
      },
      "notification": {
        "body": "This is a message from FCM to web",
        "requireInteraction": "true",
        "badge": "/badge-icon.png"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or Send a Push Notification using topic

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com//v1/projects/<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>/messages:send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: bearer <YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>

{
  "message": {
    "topic": "matchday"
    "notification": {
      "title": "Background Message Title",
      "body": "Background message body"
    },
    "webpush": {
      "fcm_options": {
        "link": "https://dummypage.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For One Signal, Visit this [Link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk) for more information. Also, alternatively, you can use web sockets, if you don't want premade services.